# How to produce a bigger rotational velocity from two rotational velocities?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electricity, electrical-engineering

If I have two electronic motors, both running at the same voltage and current, delivering the same rotational velocity, how could I produce a bigger rotational velocity from them?
[image]

Comment: Would gearing them up be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the first and the second rotational velocity of two electronics motors are $\overrightarrow{\omega}_1$ and $\overrightarrow{\omega}_2$, respectively.

To achieve the highest resultant of these vector, we must adding them in parallel direction at the same rotational axis ($\theta = 0$).

$$
 \begin{align*}
    \overrightarrow{\omega}_{\mathrm{resultant,max}} 
      &= \overrightarrow{\omega_1} + \overrightarrow{\omega_2} \\
    \left|\overrightarrow{\omega}_{\mathrm{resultant,max}}\right| 
      &= \sqrt{\left|\overrightarrow{\omega_1}\right|^2 + \left|\overrightarrow{\omega_2}\right|^2 + 2 \left|\overrightarrow{\omega_1}\right|\left|\overrightarrow{\omega_1}\right|\cos{\theta}}\\
      &= 2\omega
  \end{align*}
$$

$$
    \mathfrak{GOD\,Bless\,You}
$$

Comment: So basically if I have $n$ motors everyone with a $\omega$ rotational velocity, I can make up a rotational velocity of $n \omega$ by adding the motor at the same rotational axis? Just like this: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/509161gygysgz.png

Comment: $$\mathfrak{GOD\,Bless\,You}$$

Comment: Right.
Or using a belt to combine their rotational speed in the same axis of rotation.
This second method could save the amount of space where the $n$ motor in that space.
$$
    \mathfrak{Freed\,to \,live\,through\,the\,death\,of\,another}
$$